# Are Windows Backup Files (.bkf) compressed?

Tags: ntfs, disk-space-utilization, backup

I'm running out of diskspace on a server - i've got a directory containing around 20gb of bkf files, which are backups of an ADAM store.

I'm thinking of applying NTFS compression to the folder to free up some space, is this a fruitless endeavor?

Thanks!!

Comment: Looking at the NTBackup/Microsoft Tape Format wiki shows no sign that this format involves data compression 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTBackup
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Tape_Format

Comment: There's only one way to find out...

Answer (score 1):

Well - I found out.  These babies can be compressed.

I applied ntfs compression to my folder of 20gb of bkf - it freed about 2GB of space!